# What 4K modes does MacBook Pro (Late 2011, Radeon HD6750M) support?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have a MacBook Pro Late 2011, and I'm planning to buy a 4K monitor (http://www.samsung.com/levant/consumer/computers-peripherals/monitors/led-monitor/LU28D590DS/ZN).

However, all the Internet is bloated about 4K support with different answers about 4K support on MBPs. Some say it's not possible, some say only at 30 or 24Hz, some say with multistream etc.

What can I exactly get with late 2011 MacBook Pro (Mavericks 10.9.4) in terms of 4K?

Comment: did you purchase this monitor, and if so were you able to get it to work?

Comment: @mustafa.0x I've ordered it (through my workplace, not myself) and still waiting for it to arrive.

Comment: I've only been able to get it to work so far using the resolution 800x600 @ 56Hz. (update: the highest resolution I can get it to work at is 1024x768 @ 60Hz)

Comment: @mustafa.0x MBP and 800x600? Definitely a driver problem.

Comment: I was able to get 4k to work using http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00DOZHL82

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a Dell P2815Q monitor (nearly 4K) connected to my MacBookPro Early 2011 running 10.9.4 (13E28)
[image: About This Mac - Displays]

[image]

Comment: Next time you take a screenshot, please have the window in focus (i.e. have it be your active window).

Comment: hmm, my late 2011 has 512MB version of the same card. is your graphics card driving your monitor at 3840x2160? how are you connecting it? does it display at 30Hz or 60Hz?

Comment: @Can-Poyrazoğlu It is being driven at 3840X2160 at 30Hz. It is connected using the Mini-DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable that came with the monitor.

Comment: Tajh, did you manage to run this setup for a longer period of time (without the GPU / motherboard of the MBP getting damaged because of overheating etc.)? I've got the same early 2011 17" MBP (model 8,3), with this very card (AMD Radeon HD 6750M 1GB), and I'd like to buy a 4k screen for this machine. I need a bigger screen anyway, and it's nonsense buying less than 4k from my perspective - even though 30 Hz of course aren't ideal... I'll probably upgrade to a newer MBP in a year or so, and will be able to run the screen @ 60Hz then (so probably not this Dell screen, I read it may not support m

Comment: I have the same system, and purchased the [U28D590D](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00IEZGWI2/) but it isn't working. Know how I might be able to get it to work?

Comment: @MickyB I have no heat problems. I use the Dell 4k screen mostly for text editing an average of 8 hours per day over the last three months.  The only time the MacBook fan(s) spin up to audible levels is when a web site is flash heavy.  This happens with or without the Dell.

Comment: You have no heat problems but... you call your MacBook "Furnace".

Comment: +1 @Maroloccio Ha, yeah. "Furnace" doesn't bode very well.

Answer (score 1):

[From the official source](http://support.apple.com/kb/sp644)

Graphics and video support

> AMD Radeon HD 6750M graphics processor with 512MB of GDDR5 memory on
>   2.2GHz configuration; or AMD Radeon HD 6770M graphics processor with 1GB of GDDR5 memory on 2.4GHz configuration.
>
> Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native
>   resolution on the built-in display and up to 2560 by 1600 pixels on an
>   external display, both at millions of colors.

Sorry, you will not get 4k resolution due to the Graphics card you have.

Comment: thanks for your feedback - but 1. it apparently works for Tajh 2. I always build in more RAM than Apple specifies as being possible (usually the MBP takes double the amount, my MBP runs smoothly since 2 years or so with 16GB) 3. I don't have one of the cards you mention here - see above 4. there's other possibilities, which Apple doesn't take into account - of course they write their specs for general users, not for IT freaks. I'm an IT administrator, though usually working in the Windows field (but also about 15 years of Mac experience). Of course it's also possible to install other drivers,

Comment: Glad you got a solution, even when using it at slower then normal refresh rate. 50 or 60 Hz is standard to avoid flickering, while at 30 Hz screen will change (refresh) slower leading to effects visible to human eye. If that does not bother you then go ahead.

Comment: @MickyB It means 512/1000 MB of Video ram on the video card, not RAM in the machine.