# 4k60 over Thunderbolt 1?

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt, 4k, displayport

I own a 2011 MacBook Pro which has Thunderbolt Gen 1 (MacBook Pro 8,2).  I know that TBolt1 is capable of 10Gbps, and the bitrate of 4k60 video is about ~5.7Gpbs.  Is it possible to drive a 4k monitor at 60hz with my MBP?

```
Model Name:                 MacBook Pro
Model Identifier:           MacBookPro8,2
Processor Name:             Intel Core i7
Processor Speed:            2.2 GHz
Number of Processors:       1
Total Number of Cores:      4
L2 Cache (per Core):        256 KB
L3 Cache:                   6 MB
Memory:                     8 GB
```

So TL;DR can I do 4k60 with my MBP?

Comment: No, your video card doesn't support it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MacBook Pro model came with either an AMD Radeon HD 6490M or 6750M and Intel HD Graphics 3000 as its graphics card options.

While your MBP does support up to two Thunderbolt displays in the following modes: dual display extended and video mirroring, it's only capable of an external resolution of up to 2560x1600 pixels.

Unfortunately, this resolution output falls below 4K resolution which is basically in the order of 4000x2000 pixels.

However, the maximum resolution of your 15.4" built in display is 1680x1050 pixels, so while you can't output 4K resolution to an  external display, the 2560x1600 pixels you can output is still an improvement.

Comment: It appears to be able to do 4k30: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/136891/what-4k-modes-does-macbook-pro-late-2011-radeon-hd6750m-support

Comment: Yes, from the link you shared it does appear someone has been able to output _nearly_ 4K and at 30Hz. That certainly isn't officially supported by Apple, and it's not at the 60Hz your question was asking about, but perhaps you will ave the same luck? What are the exact specs of your graphics card (your question never stated)? A key factor to your chances will be the amount of VRAM you have. Also, what version of macOS are you running? This will have a big impact as Apple made some significant changes in recent versions.

Comment: I'm running 10.12, and I have the 6750M

Comment: The amount of VRAM you have is important and the 6750M actually came with various amounts depending on your exact model. Can you check System Profiler to get the exact amount your model has.

Comment: According to System Information, I have 1GB

Comment: Ok, well, that's the best case scenario, so you may have some success. Keep in mind though (1) what you want to do isn't officially supported by Apple, so there's no telling what potential stresses you may be causing your MBP by doing this; and (2) that it's not going to be at 60Hz, so there will be some screen flicker which you may or may not notice. If you do go ahead, please let us know how you go.

Comment: Will do.  I'll probably stick with 1080p maybe 1440p if I decide to get an external monitor.  But I'l definitely keep you guys filled in.